# Newton-Raphson or EM Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithms

Is there any implementation of Newton-Raphson or EM Algorithm? Can I get the source code of it?

I tried googling, but didn't come across any. So asking here.

Thanks!

Comment: Newton's method can apply in a lot of contexts, and EM is really a whole class of algorithms. I think you need to narrow down your purpose.

Comment: Hi Sean, I got the answer I was looking for. I know it might be too broad but this is exactly the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scikit learn has the EM algorithm [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html).

Source code is available.

And if you are an R fan the `mclust` package is available [here](http://www.stat.washington.edu/mclust/).

Comment: Implementation of newton's method also exists in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) and the source is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L45)